# Accuracy, training, test loss doesn't change throughout all the epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on a text classification problem with a binary output 0 or 1. The accuracy, train loss and test loss remains the same. The accuracy is exact the same for all the epochs. All the steps looks very correct. I had tried out several ways to figure out what is going wrong. Nothing actually worked. Please help.

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_layers, num_classes, input_size, hidden_size,vocab,dropout):
        super(RNN,self).__init__()
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.sequence_len = sequence_len
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(len(vocab),input_size)
        nn.init.xavier_normal_(self.embedding.weight)
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size, hidden_size,num_layers,dropout = dropout, nonlinearity = 'tanh', batch_first=True, bias = True, bidirectional = False)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 1)
        nn.init.xavier_normal_(self.linear.weight)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
        
    def forward(self,x):
        lens = list(map(len, x))
        padded = pad_sequence(x, batch_first=True)
        output_embedding=self.embedding(padded)   

        packed = pack_padded_sequence(input = output_embedding,lengths = lens, batch_first=True, enforce_sorted=False)
        input_rnn = packed
        h011 = torch.zeros(1,32,3)
        output_11, hidden_11 = self.rnn(input_rnn,h011)
        output_padded, output_lengths = pad_packed_sequence(output_11, batch_first=True)
        final_output_11 = self.linear(hidden_11)        
        prob_11 = self.sigmoid(final_output_11)
        return output_padded, hidden_11, prob_11
```

```
   num_layers = 1
   num_classes = 2
   input_size = 5
   hidden_size = 3
   criterion = nn.BCELoss()
   sequence_len = 1
   dropout = 0.5
   rnn = RNN(num_layers, num_classes, input_size, hidden_size,vocab,dropout)
   epochs = 10
   lr = 0.01
   weight_decay=0.011
```

```
   def train_loop(model,criterion,optimizer,train_loader,valid_loader,epochs):
    train_losses= []
    valid_losses= []

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        train_loss=0
        for label,text in train_loader:
            
            output,hidden,prob = rnn.forward(text)
            prob = torch.tensor([item.item() for sublist in prob for item in sublist],dtype = torch.float32)
            label = torch.tensor(label, dtype = torch.float32)
            loss=criterion(prob,label)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.requires_grad = True
            
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            train_loss += loss.item()
        train_loss=train_loss/len(train_loader)
        
        
        valid_loss=0
        
        with torch.no_grad():
            correct=0
            total=0
            for label,text in valid_loader:
                output,hidden,prob = rnn.forward(text)
                prob = torch.tensor([item.item() for sublist in prob for item in sublist],dtype = torch.float32)
                label = torch.tensor(label, dtype = torch.float32)
                loss=criterion(prob,label)
                valid_loss += loss.item()
                p = torch.tensor([1 if i > 0.5 else 0 for i in prob.data], dtype = torch.float32)
                #predicted = torch.max(p, 1)
                
                total += label.size(0)
                
                correct += (p == label).sum().item()
            valid_loss=valid_loss/len(valid_loader)
            accuracy = 100 * correct / total
            print(accuracy)
        scheduler.step(accuracy)
        train_losses.append(train_loss)
        valid_losses.append(valid_loss)
        
        print(f'Epoch {epoch+1:<2d}/{epochs} --> Train Loss: {train_loss:.4f} |  Valid Loss: {valid_loss:.4f}')
```

```
   from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import StepLR
   from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import ReduceLROnPlateau
   optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(rnn.parameters(), lr=0.01)
   scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, mode='max', factor=0.4, patience=5, 
   verbose=True) # need to change scheduler.step

   train_loop(rnn,criterion,optimizer,train_loader,valid_loader,epochs)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I don't know your data at all, but it seems your RNN is too simple to handle your data. Try making the network much complicated (more layers, neurons,...). It's just and idea, since it seems you can't improve the accuracy from the first epoch. Maybe reducing the learning rate could be a good option.

Comment: Your model might be initialized in a local minimum. maybe increasing the learning rate could be a good option since your scheduler will decrease it later anyway.